# Destructuring argument: TS2339 Property does not exist

Tags: typescript, tsc

I'm working with an existing javascript function.   I started using the --checkJs option, with typescript checking the code even though it is in a .js file.   The function uses de-structuring on it's final argument, which seems to be important, and confusing...

```
export function foldFlowLines(
  text, indent, mode,
  { indentAtStart, lineWidth = 80, minContentWidth = 20, onFold, onOverflow }
  ) {
   // ...body containing...

   if (overflow && onOverflow) onOverflow()
   if (folds.length === 0) return text
   if (onFold) onFold()

   // ...
}
```

I'm getting the following message:

```
src/foldFlowLines.js:42:66 - error TS2339: Property 'onOverflow' does not exist on type 
'{ indentAtStart?: number; lineWidth?: number; minContentWidth?: number; onFold: Function; }'.

42   { indentAtStart, lineWidth = 80, minContentWidth = 20, onFold, onOverflow }
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

tsc seems to have inferred somehow that `onFold` is a funcion, which is fine, but somehow it's complaining about `onOverflow` not being present.    Can anyone explain why I'm getting this message?

**Typescript Version 3.7.5**

PS: I updated the typescript package to latest version 3.8.3, same result.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was an error in the JSDoc comments!

Here's the original, with the subtle error:

```js
/**
 * Tries to keep input at up to `lineWidth` characters, splitting only on spaces
 * not followed by newlines or spaces unless `mode` is `'quoted'`. Lines are
 * terminated with `\n` and started with `indent`.
 *
 * @param {string} text
 * @param {string} indent
 * @param {string} [mode='flow'] `'block'` prevents more-indented lines
 *   from being folded; `'quoted'` allows for `\` escapes, including escaped
 *   newlines
 * @param {Object} options
 * @param {number} [options.indentAtStart] Accounts for leading contents on
 *   the first line, defaulting to `indent.length`
 * @param {number} [options.lineWidth=80]
 * @param {number} [options.minContentWidth=20] Allow highly indented lines to
 *   stretch the line width
 * @param {function} options.onFold Called once if the text is folded
 * @param {function} options.onFold Called once if any line of text exceeds
 *   lineWidth characters
 */
export function foldFlowLines(
  text,
  indent,
  mode,
  { indentAtStart, lineWidth = 80, minContentWidth = 20, onFold, onOverflow }
) { 
//... 
}
```

The final `@param` needed to be changed from **`options.onFold`** to **`options.onOverflow`**.